# INotifyPropertyChanged not working for static properties in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` for static property in my code. But it doesn't affect UI. Here i have added my code. Anyone has idea on this. Thanks in Advance.

```
     private static string dateTimeValue;
     public static string DateTimeValue { get { return dateTimeValue; } set 
        { dateTimeValue = value; RaisedPropertyChanged("DateTimeValue"); } }

    static void RaisedPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
     }
The xaml code is,
    <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Static local:LoginPageModel.DateTimeValue}, UpdateSourceEventName=PropertyChanged}">
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your 'LoginPageModel' class is static as well because you're using the 'x:Static' markup extension, in that case, your code seems correct except the 'UpdateSourceEventName=PropertyChanged' is not be necessary and this may be causing your UI not to update.